# How to use findNumbers in Google PhoneNumberLib?

Tags: java, python, libphonenumber, phonenumberutils

I am using [Googles Phone Number Library](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber) to find phone numbers in a text file. That phone number can be in any format or from any country. Regex is not solving the problem. I was coding in [3rd party python version](https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers) of it, 
 but it is not that good and I can't find a way to use FindNumbers function. How to use it in Java or even better in python?

Here is an Example: 440-991-6659(F)

Comment: Perhaps you can edit your question to show examples of the numbers that are not found, _and_ the arguments that you are passing to `PhoneNumberMatcher`?

Comment: @snakecharmerb- Done

Answer (score 0):

IN the python port that you link to, there is a `PhoneNumberMatcher` class that provides the `FindNumbers` functionality.  The code is [here](https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers/blob/dev/python/phonenumbers/phonenumbermatcher.py#L456).

From the project's README:

> Sometimes, you've got a larger block of text that may or may not have
>   some phone numbers inside it. For this, the PhoneNumberMatcher object
>   provides the relevant functionality; you can iterate over it to
>   retrieve a sequence of PhoneNumberMatch objects. Each of these match
>   objects holds a PhoneNumber object together with information about
>   where the match occurred in the original string.
>
> ```
> >>> text = "Call me at 510-748-8230 if it's before 9:30, or on 703-4800500 after 10am."
> >>> for match in phonenumbers.PhoneNumberMatcher(text, "US"):
> ...     print match
> ...
> PhoneNumberMatch [11,23) 510-748-8230
> PhoneNumberMatch [51,62) 703-4800500
> >>> for match in phonenumbers.PhoneNumberMatcher(text, "US"):
> ...     print phonenumbers.format_number(match.number, phonenumbers.PhoneNumberFormat.E164)
> ...
> +15107488230
> +17034800500
> ```

Comment: When I am using this it's not able to find all phone numbers.